# Merge rasters results as a black image

Tags: gdal, merge

I merged four rasters using GDAL > Miscellaneous Raster > Merge

The result is a black image (only 0 value everywhere on it) of four images extents.

I've executed this geo-algorithm before without any problems... until today.

What is going on?

[image: All of 4 raster to merge]
[image: Parameters to merge rasters]
[image: The results of merging]

Aditional data: OS Linux Ubuntu 20.04

QGIS version 3.16.7-Hannover
QGIS code revision 04717438

Comment: Did you recalculate the statistics on the merged raster?  Color ramps don't work well with -FLOAT_MAX,FLOAT_MAX range.

Comment: Are you sure that Float32 is the right data type for you? The image in the screen capture looks like a typical 8-bit (Byte) satellite image.

Comment: I tried with BYTE, but i get same results, except it was the opossite because i get full white image, so I decided to downloaded QGIS 3.18 version and I did it the merge process again and it works!. I really do not know what happened but for now i will use both versions while i descover what is going on.